# AIR 3 Native Extensions for Android: How to add external JAR to Java Android Project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have added external jar to Java android project and exported as a jar.

and i am using the exported jar in my AIR mobile library. In my Mobile application, referring library project.

Code which refers to the external library is not executing(in Java android project)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an ANE for the jar?

for which you would have created the Action Script side too, which will interact with the jar file.

You would be accessing the AS side of the code in your project

simply put ANE = JAR + AS, you call the AS side.

Link for more details (you probably already know this :) .. .)

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried Native Extension for VIBRATE example and that is working fine.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html

I have inserted few lines of code which will send a email in the "call" function of "VibrationVibrateFunction" class.

```
@Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] passedArgs) 
       {
        FREObject result = null;

           VibrationExtensionContext vbc = (VibrationExtensionContext)context;

           try 
           {
                 // Mail class uses external jars(mail.jar, Activity.jar)         
                 Mail m = new Mail("nata....@gmail.com", "password"); 
                 m.addAttachment("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20110906_173932.jpg"); 
                 m.send() 

                     // Vibrate Code
                 FREObject fro = passedArgs[0];
                 int duration = fro.getAsInt();
                 vbc.vb.vibrate(duration);
           }catch (Exception e){

           }

           return result;
       }
```

The email code will work fine in the Java android project and i need to add external jars to perform email.

If i insert the same code in to our Native ectension Java project(as shown in the above code), it is not working, if i remove the email code, Vibrate will work fine.

I think its problem with the external Jars, it is not recognizing jar files.

Please let me know if you know how to add external jars.

Thank you